# Why can't I start a bounty on my question?

Tags: support, bounty

I want to start a bounty on [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/12337/6173), however the `[start a bounty]` link isn't there.

I should meet the requirements [posted on the SO meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/54772/158605). I have the required rep, the question is over 2 days old, and I have never created a bounty on this site before.

Are the requirements for starting a bounty here different from any other SE site? Or is there something else going on that would prevent me from starting a bounty on my question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I miss my mark, right this second it's still about 2 hours away from "2 days old", by the UTC timestamps.

But my math could be off.

However, I can get you more attention (and you could too) by visiting our [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap) to hook one of the regulars to get their eyes on it faster, and hopefully get them to find their friends who can answer it.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right. I didn't notice the time the question was created, only that the `you can start a bounty in x days` message was gone